# Trend stationary and difference stationary simultaneously

Tags: time-series, trend, unit-root, stationarity

Can a time series be both trend stationary and difference stationary at the same time? In this situation how do we approach the problem?

Comment: What are the definitions?  If you mean, stationary after removing trend and stationary after differencing then the answer is yes.  If you have a series n the ARIMA class kth order differencing can remove a kth order polynomial trend. The operation (transformation) can make the resulting model stationary and it does remove trends of a certain kind. But I am not familiar with your terminology and others may be also.  Please clarify.

Comment: Michael Chernick notes correctly that differencing removes polynomial trends, but it also introduces unit root MA terms, which should be avoided. Thus polynomial (including linear) trends should not be removed by differencing. Differencing should only be used for removing stochastic trends (unit roots).

Answer (score 5):

It certainly is possible that we may have a process that has both a deterministic time trend and a unit root, for example:

$$y_t = \delta t + y_{t-1} + u_t \tag{1}$$

with $u_t$ being white noise, $u_t \sim WN(0, \sigma^2_u)$.

To achieve second-order stationarity in the above case, we first *subtract the first lag from both sides* (and we do *not* apply the Diferrence operator on both sides), so we get

$$\Delta y_t = \delta t  + u_t \tag{2}$$

(**NOTE**: that if we have applied the first-diference operator in the first step instead of just subtracting $y_{t-1}$ from both sides we would obtain the expression

$$\Delta y_t = \Delta\delta t + \Delta y_{t-1} + \Delta u_t = \delta + \Delta y_{t-1} + (u_t-u_{t-1}) \tag{3}$$

which may remove the deterministic time trend but it leaves us with a unit root in first-differences *and* introduces an MA term complicating matters. So this approach is to be avoided.)

After obtaining $(2)$ (which does not involve estimation) one can visually check whether the series appears to contain a deterministic time trend. If it does, we then de-trend by *estimating* the $\delta$ coefficient and use the residuals from this estimation step as our second-order stationary series... which, strictly speaking, *it is not* second-order stationary, due to the fact that we have to estimate $\delta$. But the deviation from stationarity is bearable.

Assume we do it by applying OLS to $(2)$ with a sample of size $T$. Then we will get

$$\hat \delta = \delta + \sum_{s=1}^T\left(\frac{s}{\sum_{s=1}^T s^2}\right)u_s$$

and the residual series will be
$$\hat u_t = u_t - t\cdot  \frac {\sum_{s=1}^Tsu_s}{\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2} = \left (1-\frac {t^2}{\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2}\right)u_t - t\cdot  \frac {\sum_{s\neq t}^Tsu_s}{\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2}$$

The variance of the residual will then be

$$\text{Var}(\hat u_t) = \sigma^2_u\cdot \left[\left(1-\frac {t^2}{\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2}\right)^2 + \frac{t^2\sum_{s\neq t}^Ts^2}{\left(\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2\right)^2}\right]$$

which thankfully simplifies to

$$\text{Var}(\hat u_t) = \sigma^2_u\cdot \left(1-\frac {t^2}{\sum_{s=1}^Ts^2}\right) $$

So the variance of the residual series is not constant but depends on $t$. The relative difference in the variances of each element of the series depends also on the sample size. For example for a sample size of $T=50$ observations, the variance of $u_{50}$ is approximately $6$% lower than the variance of $u_1$ (the latter being the closest to the true variance of the white noise term). For a sample size of $T=1000$ it is just $0.3$% smaller. 
Also the term involving $t$ converges to zero rather fast (since the denominator is one power of $T$ greater than the numerator).  Analogous results hold also for pair-wise covariances.

We conclude that treating the residual series as second-order stationary will not lead to misleading inference, because the deviation from actual stationarity is small (except perhaps for very small samples).

Comment: This is good and supports Richard Hardy's statement. My comment was meant to be prefaced by the time series being in the ARIMA class. So the deterministic linear term in your example would eliminate  the series from being ARIMA. If the process is ARIMA the proper number of differences will remove stochastics trend and can make the model stationary (at least 2nd order stationary). Now my mistake is that I am inconsistent in my claim.  There was no deterministic trend to remove from my ARIMA model so it doesn't do both.

Comment: @AlexcosPapadopoulos Your example shows a time series model which is initially nonstationary because of a first order autoregressive term with the AR parameter =1.  The first step is just an algebraic manipulation.  The second step takes the model which has the form of a linear regression in t.  Delta can be estimated by least squares. Then you say that the series becomes the estimated residuals from the detrending.  Does that make it stationary? The key demonstration is to take a first difference before doing anything else. But does that actually give you the last equation that you display?

Comment: i am now not sure that your example achieves what Richard Hardy claimed.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for the feedback. I am looking into it to see what may need to be changed in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thank you for insisting on this one. I have modified my answer and gained a few insights while doing it.

Comment: @AlexPapadopoulos I think you filled in the gaps and answered my questions. Since in my answer I made the restriction that the process was in the ARIMA class I am pointing out that your examples are not ARIMA models.  But the question never made that restriction so this answer is fine and probably adds a lot for the OP as well as explaining Richard Hardy's point.

Comment: @MichaelChernick and Alecos, I am glad I could contribute my two cents to this discussion. Alecos, your answer is great -- as always!

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks Richard, I do appreciate your kind words.

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos Could you explain a bit more why introducing the MA-term "complicates matters"? I tried to read about this and found it might render the process "non-invertible" which can create issues with identifiability, but I don't really understand this. Thanks!

Comment: @jmb You may want to consult pp 64-67 of Hamilton's Time Series Analysis. In the case above we have introduced an MA(1) component with coefficient equal to 1, which makes the MA(1) non-invertible, meaning that there is no AR($\infty$) representation for it. But then, how are you going to forecast the series based on its past realizations?

Comment: @Alecos Papadopoulos Excellent, thank you so much for the swift reply!